# Ajax Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl, cross-domain

I am using http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/
I have set up my local Ampps server as said on the page.
Examples given on the page are running successfully.

My test.html contains:

```
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?uri=(http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred/run/hhpred)&amp;method=post&amp;postdata=(sequence_input=&amp;sequence_file=target.seq&amp;informat=fas&amp;submitform=Submit%2Bjob&amp;hhpred_dbs%5B%5D=%2Fcluster%2Ftoolkit%2Fproduction%2Fdatabases%2Fhhpred%2Fnew_dbs%2Fpdb70_6Jun13&amp;genomes_first=true&amp;prefilter=hhblits&amp;maxhhblitsit=3&amp;ss_scoring=2&amp;alignmode=local&amp;more_options_on=false&amp;Ehhblitsval=1E-3&amp;cov_min=20&amp;qid_min=0&amp;mact=0.3&amp;compbiascorr=1&amp;maxseq=1&amp;width=80&amp;Pmin=20&amp;maxlines=100&amp;jobid=&amp;mail=)">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(ACD.responseText);
</script> `
```

and ACD.js contains:

```
my @allowed_uris = (
    'uri=(http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred/run/hhpred)&method=post&postdata=(sequence_input=&sequence_file=target.seq&informat=fas&submitform=Submit+job&hhpred_dbs%5B%5D=%2Fcluster%2Ftoolkit%2Fproduction%2Fdatabases%2Fhhpred%2Fnew_dbs%2Fpdb70_6Jun13&genomes_first=true&prefilter=hhblits&maxhhblitsit=3&ss_scoring=2&alignmode=local&more_options_on=false&Ehhblitsval=1E-3&cov_min=20&qid_min=0&mact=0.3&compbiascorr=1&maxseq=1&width=80&Pmin=20&maxlines=100&jobid=&mail=)'
    );
```

in the `my @allowed_uris` variable. Rest of ACD.js is same as http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/ACD-source.txt

I want to submit this form http://toolkit.tuebingen.mpg.de/hhpred and get data with AJAX. It is giving `500 Internal Error`.

Can anybody explain how to do it?

Comment: 500 means something is wrong on your server side, try watching logs and raising error reporting level

Comment: I cannot control server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test.html

```
src="http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?...
```

needs to be changed to

```
src="cgi-bin/ACD/ACD.js?...
```

'Twas easy, but hidden :)